# socketio triggers events even though socket disconnected

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a server which emit every sec. a timeupdate event.

when some client are connected to the server i start, after 10 sek a socket.disconnect(true)...

socket.on('disconnect') tells me (after 10sec) its disconnected
The browser / Webpage also after 10.sec stops to update the time

but the console.log() in 'timeUpdate' emit still triggers on all sockets?!

```
setInterval(function(){
   now = new Date();
   myEmitter.emit('timeUpdate');
 }, 1000);

 ...
 ...

 io.on('connection', (socket) => { 
  var clientIp = socket.request.connection.remoteAddress;
  console.log(now+': Client connected ID: '+socket.id+' - IP: '+clientIp+''.green);  


  setTimeout(() => socket.disconnect(true), 10000);

  socket.on('disconnect', (reason) => {
     console.log(reason);
   });



   myEmitter.on('timeUpdate', function(msg){
    socket.emit('timeUpdate', now);
    console.log(now+': ad: '+socket.id+' - IP: '+clientIp+''.green);  
  });

});
```

```
192.168.178.27
Tue May 07 2019 09:26:55 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00): ad: KKEtFsvMuBYj3IHfAAAB - IP: ::ffff:192.168.178.27
Tue May 07 2019 09:26:55 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00): ad: gmCJHquzy0t8cs2FAAAC - IP: ::ffff:192.168.178.27
Tue May 07 2019 09:26:55 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00): ad: wxv8sp82lbzX_Qs4AAAD - IP: ::ffff:192.168.178.27
server namespace disconnect
Tue May 07 2019 09:26:56 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00): ad: Wnm9lqwuBf3gYY9yAAAA - IP: ::ffff:192.168.178.27
Tue May 07 2019 09:26:56 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00): ad: KKEtFsvMuBYj3IHfAAAB - IP: ::ffff:192.168.178.27
Tue May 07 2019 09:26:56 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00): ad: gmCJHquzy0t8cs2FAAAC - IP: ::ffff:192.168.178.27
Tue May 07 2019 09:26:56 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00): ad: wxv8sp82lbzX_Qs4AAAD - IP: ::ffff:192.168.178.27
server namespace disconnect
server namespace disconnect
Tue May 07 2019 09:26:57 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00): ad: Wnm9lqwuBf3gYY9yAAAA - IP: ::ffff:192.168.178.27
Tue May 07 2019 09:26:57 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00): ad: KKEtFsvMuBYj3IHfAAAB - IP: ::ffff:192.168.178.27
Tue May 07 2019 09:26:57 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00): ad: gmCJHquzy0t8cs2FAAAC - IP: ::ffff:192.168.178.27
Tue May 07 2019 09:26:57 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00): ad: wxv8sp82lbzX_Qs4AAAD - IP: ::ffff:192.168.178.27
Tue May 07 2019 09:26:58 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00): ad: Wnm9lqwuBf3gYY9yAAAA - IP: ::ffff:192.168.178.27
Tue May 07 2019 09:26:58 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00): ad: KKEtFsvMuBYj3IHfAAAB - IP: ::ffff:192.168.178.27
Tue May 07 2019 09:26:58 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00): ad: gmCJHquzy0t8cs2FAAAC - IP: ::ffff:192.168.178.27
Tue May 07 2019 09:26:58 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00): ad: wxv8sp82lbzX_Qs4AAAD - IP: ::ffff:192.168.178.27
Tue May 07 2019 09:26:59 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00): ad: Wnm9lqwuBf3gYY9yAAAA - IP: ::ffff:192.168.178.27
Tue May 07 2019 09:26:59 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00): ad: KKEtFsvMuBYj3IHfAAAB - IP: ::ffff:192.168.178.27
```

Comment: Nobody knows a reason?

Comment: can you supply a little more information and separate out the client and server code in two different blocks so that I could copy your code and check it on my local, I think I can help here, if you give me a little more information.